# Failed to connect to the remote extension host server

Tags: vscode-remote

after port forwarding, the error message shows in the notification center:

```
Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Connection error: Unauthorized client refused.)
```

Comment: I think you're just not authorized. Check your password/ssh key.

Comment: I did observe that error using the `Remote - Containers` extension. I used Code from the Arch repositories. Using the Microsoft binaries resolved the issue for me.